# Python library for image to font conversion

Tags: python, file-converter, font, image, converter

I am looking for a library that allows me to convert images into fonts. I am not looking for Optical Character Recognition software.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by converting images into fonts? A font is a style of character (like Times or Arial). If you mean characters, then you want OCR.

Comment: OCR gives you only the text. Not the .ttf file.

Comment: So you want to create a digital font from scanning a printed sample?

Comment: Yeah, but not a scanned image but an image.